# How to write a BufferedReader into slf4j logger

Tags: java, slf4j

I have a BufferReader which I need to dump into a slf4j logger.

```
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
```

I want to dump the stdError into a slf4j logger. Is there a library I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Get the contents from BufferedReader and form a String and then write to logger.

Comment: This is somehting I tried to avoid. I want to know if there is a library I can use.

Comment: You can also use like this. LOG.info(new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(process.getErrorStream()))); You have to use Apache Commons IO for this.

Comment: @Sambit In `Process` the input and the error streams are updated incrementally. I would favor rather an incremental logging to not lose any information if a crash JVM occurs before logging the entire output.

Comment: @davidxxx Sir, yes, what you have suggested is good and recommended.

Answer (score 1):

`Loggers` are not `java.io` I/O streams and are not designed either to decorate them.
`Loggers` are designed to write specific records in some appenders. So, if you need to record information returned by `process.getErrorStream()`, the cleaner thing to do is to delegate for each read line of `process.getErrorStream()`  to `Logger.error(readLine)`.

Really easy to write :

```
Process p = ...;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
String readLine = null;
while ((readLine = reader.readLine())!=null){
    logger.error(readLine);
}
```

Logging incrementally (line by line) matters because if you perform that task only at the end with a single big log entry and that the JVM crashed before reaching the "big" log entry processing, you would have logged nothing.